# PHP: Accessing variables stored in a function

Tags: php

I have a set of PHP variables (that start with `$cta`). I use a PHP 'If' test, to change the values of these variables  depending on the values of other variables.

I use these variables in several locations in my PHP file (and wrap the variables in different HTML code depending on the location), so I want to store the 'If' testing code in a function.

That way, my code will be more efficient, as the 'If' test will be in one place.

Here is my function:

```
function calltoaction {

 if ($cta_settings == 'cta_main') {
                $cta_prompt = 'We are ready for your call';
                $cta_button = 'Contact Us';
            }
($cta_settings == 'cta_secondary') {
                $cta_prompt = 'Call us for fast professional service';
                $cta_button = 'Call Us';
            }
}
```

Now that I have the function, how do I access the $cta variables inside of it?

E.g. The following doesn't work:

```
<?php 
calltoaction();
print '<p>' . $cta_prompt . '</p>;
print '<span>' . $cta_button . '</span>;
?>
```

(The examples presented above are a cut down version, my full code is a bit more complex).

Comment: declare `$cta_prompt` as global variable

Comment: `global $cta_prompt, $cta_button;` (inside the function)

Comment: Don't use globals, both of the preceding comments are offering very bad advice.

Comment: or (better) have your fonction take your `$cta_settings` as input parameter and return a pair of values for `$cta_prompt` and `$cta_button`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you wanted to do something like this:

```
<?php
function callToAction($cta_settings)
{

    if ($cta_settings == 'cta_main') {
        $cta_prompt = 'We are ready for your call';
        $cta_button = 'Contact Us';
    } elseif ($cta_settings == 'cta_secondary') {
        $cta_prompt = 'Call us for fast professional service';
        $cta_button = 'Call Us';
    } else {
        $cta_prompt = 'Call us for fast professional service';
        $cta_button = 'Call Us';
    }
    return ["cta_prompt" => $cta_prompt, "cta_button" => $cta_button];
}

$cta1 = callToAction('cta_main');
?>

<p><?php echo $cta1['cta_prompt']; ?></p>
<span><?php echo $cta1['cta_button']; ?></span>
```

Answer (score 5):

> Now that I have the function, how do I access the $cta variables inside of it?

You don't. That isn't how functions are meant to work. You also have a second bug in that `$cta_settings` won't be set inside your function, as you haven't passed it in or declared it as a global, meaning your prompt/button variables are never set anyways.

Your functions should accept inputs, and return outputs. If you want to communicate a value out of a function for use elsewhere, you should `return` it. If you need to return a complex result, use an array or an object.

You should *not* use global variables for this. Using global variables breaks the encapsulation the function is meant to provide.

In your case, I would use something like this:

```
function calltoaction($settings) {
  if ($settings == 'cta_main') {
    return array('We are ready for your call', 'Contact Us');
  } else if ($settings == 'cta_secondary') {
    return array('Call us for fast professional service', 'Call Us');
  }
}

list($prompt, $button) = calltoaction($cta_settings);
```

Note that the function accepts an argument (`$settings`) instead of referencing some global variable, and returns two values for use in the calling code. It's up to the calling code to decide on variable names for its *local* variables, as it should be - the function shouldn't be injecting variables into the global scope.

Comment: How do I access the prompt and button parts individually, so I can wrap them in HTML (I can't include the HTML inside the function, as it is different each time the function is used).

Comment: @big_smile They're individually available as variables called `$prompt` and `$button` after the above code. That is what `list` does, destructures an array into a set of variables.